# In AUTO flush mode will a commit automatically flush pending SQLs

Tags: hibernate

In Hibernate will a commit automatically flush() the session before committing?

Will the following code work (will the the property change on animal be persisted) in  `FlushMode.AUTO`?

```
Session session = <get session>;
session.beginTransaction();
Animal animal = session.load(Animal.class, 1L);
animal.hasEatenForToday(true);
session.getTransaction().commit();
```

Or do I have to include a session.flush() before the commit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes hibernate will flush all changes of persistent objects attached to current session before commiting it.